# Remove Revision History

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using Google Apps Script to run an encryption on data in a spreadsheet.  It's working fine, but that handy revision history in the spreadsheet makes it a bit of a moot point as you can simply view a version prior to the encryption.

Is there a way to delete revision histories, or to simply keep them from being created all together?

Comment: A spreadsheet coping clears the history. It can be a workaround.

Comment: Yeah, but I have outside scripts working on this spreadsheet.  Copying would change the ID and mean the scripts need to be reassigned.   The fact that other scripts are accessing it is the main reason I want to encode the data in the first place.

Comment: I assume that there is a limit of the history list. It is possible to try to make a number of dummy changes which will push out the not encrypted history.

Comment: No dice. While I can't find the actual limit on the history, with regular use they can go back four months.  I image dummy changes would  render the sheet useless for a good long while, if it didn't just time out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.
The Drive [API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/revisions/delete) for accessing revision history specifically does not delete entries on Google sheets.

Something to note revision history is only viewable by those with edit rights. View or comment only rights cannot see revision history.

One solution is to have users submit data to a very narrowly shared sheet via Google forms and set up a trigger to copy the non sensitive meta/aggregate data that you are leaving unencrypted to a more public sheet for access by untrusted users and scripts. the cell formula IMPORTRANGE() would also work it gets access permission from the person entering the formula and can therefore move data from a restricted spread sheet to a less restricted one without compromising the original sheet.

A second solution that is slightly more cumbersome, but closer to your ask, is to provide users and external scripts with access to a drive folder containing the sheet. With the ID of the folder scripts can then search for the sheet by name via the [drive api](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder), users use their eyes to find it by name. Your encryption script, once done encrypting, copies the spreadsheet using [SpreadsheetApp.copy(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#copyname)which will copy all of the formulas, formatting, data, even scripts, but not the revision history. Pass copy() the same name as the original sheet, drive file names do not have to be unique. Use the drive api to move the new spreadsheet to the folder, it should inherit the sharing of the folder by default. Again with the drive API delete the original spreadsheet. Because all users and scripts were looking for a file named X in a specific folder ID everything is still exactly where they expect to find it, but the revision history is gone.

Comment: Thank you.  It's a bit messy, and I have one or two challenges to implement but I appreciate understanding the use case and putting a bit of thought into a work around.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Google Apps Script doesn't provide a method to remove items from the revision history.

Answer (score -2):

Copy all spreadsheet, restore to the first version and then, paste de spreadsheet :)

Comment: That copies the values. Also, doesn't remove the history.

Comment: Remove the history because you restore to the first review and replace it

Comment: Maybe the behaviour has changed, but it didn't replace the history, and only pasted the values, not the formulas.

Answer (score -3):

For Google Documents I managed to get rid of the revision history by making a copy of the document. Not sure if that will work for spreadsheets too.

Comment: Please check the comments on the question. The question asker has indicated that this would change the ID of the spreadsheet and affect the functioning of their scripts. For this reason, this is not a suitable solution for them.

Comment: MartinK wants to programatically remove the revision history on the spreadsheet, not create a new spreadsheet.